# Wordpress gallery with multilang support and nested albums

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gallery, multilingual

I need to implement photo gallery on wordpress 3.6
It must support these features:

- different languages support
- categories and subcategories (albums)
- loading images with AJAX on website pages

I've tried some plugins (Nextgen and similar) but i can't find how to add description and name of each photo in different languages.
I've also tried to use standart wordpress functionality (media library, posts) but i don't think that it is correct solution.

Is it possible to implement this gallery with any plugins? Or it will be faster to write one new?

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you checked this link for [ajax image gallery](http://www.designrazzi.com/2013/wordpress-gallery-plugins/) plugins?

2) Try to use qtranslate plugin for multilingual wordpress site

These things might be helpful to you.

Thanks